# How to load values in default

Tags: java, swing, swingx, defaulttablemodel, jxtreetable

I am building a tree viewer using `JXTreeTable` and `DefaultTreeTableModel`. It will be used to show millions of objects in tree as parent and their child.

Using this code to insert value of node in tree -

```
DefaultMutableTreeTableNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode("object" + i++);
model.insertNodeInto(child, root, root.getChildCount());
```

This model have been inserted to tree earlier at loading time.

I want to show a child inserted as its value fetched from saved result one by one, but it adding complete list to model after listing finished.

How can I perform this showing listing of object dynamically?

Comment: what _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: Want to show item (node) added in tree as it fetched from saved result. Means to show list of node in tree dynamically at run time.

Comment: It is possible to add nodes to a `TreeModel` at runtime while the tree is visible, so again, what is the problem ?

Comment: Tree get visible when it all nodes get added to model.

Comment: No, still does not make any sense. You will have to be more clear. Something in the line of I want to achieve X. In the process of getting X  to work, I did Y (with some [code](http://sscce.org/)) and expected Z, but got Z*

Comment: Looks like he wants to filter a pre-populated tree by some outside reference (fetch result?), to show only specific nodes. If so: RowFilters 'R' us!